# Firebase access denied?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So I have this little code snippet that is responsible for uploading a picture to the firebase storage. For some odd reason, my access keeps getting denied. There seems to be a problem with storageRef because it goes into the if statement that prints out the  error.

```
  // will handle the  sign up of a user
    @objc func handleSignUp(){
        // first we cant to take sure that all of the fields are filled
        var profilePic: String = ""

        // will take the user selected image and load it to firebase
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
 let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).PNG")
        if let userImage = selectedImageFromPicker,let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(userImage, 0.1){

            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error ?? "")
                    return
                }
                 profilePic = (metadata?.downloadURL()!.absoluteString)!
                guard let username = self.nameTextField.text,
                    let confirmPassword = self.confirmPasswordTextField.text,
                    let email = self.emailTextField.text,
                    let password = self.passwordTextField.text,
                    !username.isEmpty,
                    !email.isEmpty,
                    !password.isEmpty,
                    !confirmPassword.isEmpty
                    else {

                        print("Required fields are not all filled!")
                        return
                }
                if self.validateEmail(enteredEmail:email) != true{
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please Enter A Valid Email", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                // will make sure user is validated before it even tries to create user

                // will make sure the password and confirm password textfields have the same value if so it will print an error
                if self.passwordTextField.text != self.confirmPasswordTextField.text {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Passwords Don't Match", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                // will authenticate a user into the authentication services with an email and passowrd
                AuthService.createUser(controller: self, email: email, password: password) { (authUser) in
                    guard let firUser = authUser else {
                        return
                    }
                    //will add user to the database
                    print(profilePic)
                    print(username)
                    UserService.create(firUser, username: username , profilePic: profilePic,location: self.userLocation!) { (user) in
                        guard let user = user else {
                            print("User successfully loaded into firebase db")
                            return
                        }
                        // will set the current user for userdefaults to work
                        print(user.profilePic)
                        print(user.username)

                        User.setCurrent(user, writeToUserDefaults: true)
                        // self.delegate?.finishSigningUp()

                        self.finishSigningUp()


                    }
                }

        })
        }
    }
```

The error is

```
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13021 "User does not have permission to access gs://eventful-3d558.appspot.com/profile_images/C0BC898A-6A6F-490F-954B-51D705CD2B23.PNG." UserInfo={object=profile_images/C0BC898A-6A6F-490F-954B-51D705CD2B23.PNG, bucket=eventful-3d558.appspot.com, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
```

If anyone knows what it is I would appreciate your help. It is preventing me from signing up users.

Comment: I seem it should not work you missing token or you did not validated your auth token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the rules of Database to accept all read and write in Database->Rules

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true
  }
}
```

By setting the database read and write rules to true, You set all the read write requests to be allowed.

If you find some permission errors in Firebase Storage then change the in Firebase Storage-> Rules

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: great but it just bypass your authentication check

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check Firebase Authentication.

Firebase Storage buckets require Firebase Authentication to upload files.

Comment: Um what do you mean?

Comment: Are you using Unauthenticated access? You may need to override security settings: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample_rules OR set up authentication https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: Maybe I should show the entire function look for edits in a second

Comment: And no im not using unauthenticated access

Comment: It looks like user authentication is happening after the upload is attempted? AuthService.createUser should be before? Authentication is needed before the profile image can be uploaded

Comment: I would assume so but it seemed to have been working before your probably right though

Comment: How would I change this around to still accomplish the same goal though

Comment: It depends if other code in your application is also authenticating the user. It only takes once.

Comment: They are independent calls, either way Authentication has to succeed first. Then you can upload the profile picture. If there is an upload error, you could always delete the user and try again.

Comment: @RonBaker Don't forget to upvote / select answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is a perfect firebase presentation that will help with this problem: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/